# Polynomial-Exponential Equation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials, exponential-function

Consider the sequence $$  x_n = \sup \{ k \in \mathbb{N} :  e^{ 2^{k}} 2^k \leq  n   \}     $$
I'm wondering if it possible to deduce that there exists $\alpha \in (0,1)$ for which $ e^{2^{x_n}} = O(n^{\alpha})  $ or a proof as to why no such $\alpha$ exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) := 2^x \exp(2^x)$ and note that $$f(m+1) -f(m) \geq (2^{m+1} -2^m) \exp(2^m) \geq 2.$$
Thus $f(m) \leq n < f(m+1)$ with $n := \lceil f(m) \rceil$ and therefore $x_n = m$. So 
$$\exp(2^{x_n}) = \exp(2^m) = f(m)/2^m \geq \frac{n-1}{2^m}.$$
Since $n \geq \exp(2^m)$, we also have $2^m \leq  \ln(n)$ and thus
$$\exp(2^{x_n}) \geq \frac{n-1}{\ln(n)}.$$
We conclude that no $\alpha \in (0,1)$ exists such that $\exp(2^{x_n}) = O(n^\alpha)$.